# Does energy to matter+antimatter conversion increase the amount of information?

Tags: energy, big-bang, information, hawking-radiation, matter

If I am not mistaken; when matter and antimatter annihilate each other and release energy, all the information except the total amount of mass, becomes lost.

So, can we say that the reversed process produces information?

Comment: Are you sure you're not mistaken? QFT is time-reversible, which wouldn't be possible if information were lost.

Comment: *all the information except the total amount of mass, becomes lost* One simple way to see that this is not true is to note that the information about the total momentum is not lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When matter and antimatter mutually annihilate, they convert to other particles such as gamma rays.  All the information that is in the original two particles is "reincarnated" in the new particles.  Note that even if more particles exist after the annihilation than before, the amount of information does not change.  This is because the states of the extra new particles will be correlated, precisely enough to guarantee conservation of the information.  This is the essence of quantum entanglement.